# Using PM2 and child_process.exec without opening new command prompts everytime

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

```
async function test() {
    const shell = require("util").promisify(require("child_process").exec);

    const shellResult = await shell("node --version");
    console.log(shellResult);
}
test();
```

In my programm, I want to do something similar like the function above. I use PM2 to start my programm. But when it comes to this function, PM2 opens a new cmd.exe everytime and closes it when its done, which gets annoying over time.

Is there a way to do something like the function above, without having PM2 opening a new cmd prompt everytime? Or is there atleast a way to open those cmd prompts in the background?

Extra information:

- Node version: 15.9.0
- PM2 version: 4.5.4
- Operating System: Windows 10
- The function above may run too fast, so its hard to tell if PM2 actually opened a new cmd.exe or not. If you would do `await shell("git pull origin master")` or something that takes a bit longer, then you can actually see that its opening and closing new cmd prompts
- I start my programm doing `pm2 start`
- ecosystem.config.js file looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  "apps": [{
    "script": "master.js",
    "node_args": ["--inspect=10000"]
  }]
};
```

Comment: This is probably the consequence of the architecture of Windows executables. Unlike unix based OSes, Windows differentiates between console apps and GUI apps whereas on unixen (like Linux and MacOS) the GUI is just an API that apps can use and all apps are console apps. There are two solutions for this: One, run your script as a service, in which case Windows will not pop up cmd.exe. The second solution is to run your script in WSL (I recommend doing it under Ubuntu for ease of Googleability when troubleshooting)

Comment: ... forgot to mention, if you run your script as a service then you don't need PM2 since Windows service manager will act as your PM2. There is a nice script that helps convert node.js programs into Windows services. Search for qckwinsvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async function test() {
    const shell = require("util").promisify(require("child_process").exec(cmd,{windowsHide:true});
    const shellResult = await shell("node --version");
    console.log(shellResult);
}
test();
```

You can use

```
windowsHide: true
```

Boolean to solve this.

RefLink: [Node.js v19.3.0: child_process.exec(command[, options][, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback)